# How to order by field if it contains number and text in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have data of address.I want to order address field to asc and desc order. 
you can see in the table there are 2 fields id, address
If i order address field to desc.It should be have to come in below order
(1)5621 EMERSON CT
(2)5600 Emerson Court
(3)5393 Conestoga Dr.
But you can see in the image. It is not working properly. address field is varchar(255). 
Can anyone please tell me what should i have to do not to solve this problem ?
Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: what is the query you used?

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `address`
ORDER BY `address`.`address` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `address` ORDER BY cast(`address` AS SIGNED) ASC
```

In the above script Type caste the address column to `int`. So If your column has value like this means `1234 street`. Mysql parse it as character so we forced mysql to parse it as int using datatype conversion function `cast` with data type signed int. so now mysql sees it as `1234` instead of `1234 street`.

But if `address` column has value like this means `junk 1234` now mysql interpret it to `0` by identify that value is started with non numeric character. so as a result if starts with number it works but not for other.

Answer (score 1):

As this "address" is a string (varchar field), so it gets ordered lexically. So, you can probably order it by

```
SELECT `address` FROM 'table` ORDER BY convert(`address`, decimal) DESC;
```

This will solve the problem.