# PHP PDO Dynamic Query Building

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$arr = array();
$from_date = '2015-01-01';
$to_date = '2015-01-31';
$order_no = '25215';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
if(!empty($from_date)&&!empty($to_date))
{
    $sql.=" WHERE txn_date BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date";
    $arr[] = ":from_date => $from_date";
    $arr[] = ":to_date => $to_date";
    $condition=true;
}
if(!empty($order_no))
{
    if($condition)
    {
       $sql.=" AND ref_number = :order_no";
       $arr[] = ":order_no => $order_no";
    }
    else
    {
       $sql.=" WHERE ref_number = :order_no";
       $arr[] = ":order_no => $order_no";
       $condition=true;
    }
}
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($arr);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When executing this query shows a warning like

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

what is wrong with it?

Comment: Your `ref_number LIKE :order_no` might as well be `ref_number = :order_no` seeing as you have no wildcard characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In variable $arr you should replace as like this for all associative index

```
$arr[':from_date'] = $from_date;
$arr[':to_date'] = $to_date;
$arr[':order_no'] = $order_no;
```

Also it is good practice to move common code in outer block instead of if/else ladder

```
if(!empty($order_no))
{
    $arr[':order_no'] = $order_no;
    if($condition)
    {
       $sql.=" AND ref_number = :order_no";
    }
    else
    {
       $sql.=" WHERE ref_number LIKE :order_no";
       $condition=true;
    }
}
```

---

As op asked in comment here is the explanation for that

```
$sql.=" WHERE txn_date BETWEEN :from_date AND :to_date";
```

Replace this with this one

```
$sql.=" WHERE date(txn_date) BETWEEN date(:from_date) AND date(:to_date)";

ref_number = :order_no
```

Instead of the above one type cast it to unsigned integer as like this in both where condition in if/else statement

```
CONVERT(ref_number,UNSIGNED INTEGER) = :order_no
```

Comment: thank you. date and order_no are string fields. how can handle it?

Comment: you mean in your sql table the column of date and order_no are varchar data type is it right?

Comment: yes. so when i executing the query no row returns. right now the array is like Array ( [from_date] => 2014-01-01 [to_date] => 2014-01-31 ). but i need like  Array ( [from_date] => '2014-01-01' [to_date] => '2014-01-31' )

Comment: either convert all column to respective data type or in your sql query type cast it see here for e.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26708807/1593365

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`$arr[] = ":from_date => $from_date";`

do

`$arr['from_date'] = $from_date;`

Read more about php arrays [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Also, what I would do is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE 1=1";
```

Then there is no need to test for `$condition` and just simply concatenate to `$sql`.

Comment: i understand. thank you. one more thing, dates and order_no are string fields. how can handle it?